# Munchkins Combat Shenanigans

Tags: munchkin

Level 1 sock puppet says players may not play cards from hand to aid or help this combat. May they use the cards that are in their unequipped zone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the items are marked "play during any combat" then yes. If the items are to be equipped, then no, you may not change what items are equipped in the middle of combat.

Comment: say for example, they have "potion of disbelief" on the board, sideways. Can they use it on the sock puppet?

Comment: You mean the one that starts with "Play during any combat"...

Comment: Yes, because it is not from your hand. Your hand specifically refers to the cards in your hand that are not on the table